# How can i assign the variable names_and_ranks to a list, with each element equal to the city name and it's corresponding rank?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
city_indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

city_names = ['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']
```

With given data (city_indices and city_names), I want to assign the variable names_and_ranks to a list, with each element equal to the city name and its corresponding rank. For example, the first element would be, "1. Buenos Aires" and the second would be "2. Toronto" by using a for loop and the lists (city_indices and city_names).

below is the code that i wrote, but still not getting result as i want as example below.

```
for city_indices in list(range(0, len(city_names))):
print(city_indices+1, city_names[city_indices])
```

For example, i want names_and_ranks should return value as below

```
names_and_ranks = []

names_and_ranks[0] # '1. Buenos Aires'
names_and_ranks[1] # '2. Toronto'
names_and_ranks[-1] # '12. Iguazu Falls'
```

I am currently learning Python and stuck in this step for 5 hours.. 
Any advise would help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be several ways, including list comprehension with *string formatting*:

```
names_and_ranks = ["%s. %s" % (i+1, name) for i, name in zip(city_indices, city_names)]
```

Or using `enumerate` instead of `zip` if the `city_names` are already in an order:

```
names_and_rank = ["%s. %s" % (i, name) for i, name in enumerate(city_names, 1)]
```

Both output the same:

```
['1. Buenos Aires',
 '2. Toronto',
 '3. Pyeongchang',
 '4. Marakesh',
 '5. Albuquerque',
 '6. Los Cabos',
 '7. Greenville',
 '8. Archipelago Sea',
 '9. Walla Walla Valley',
 '10. Salina Island',
 '11. Solta',
 '12. Iguazu Falls']
```

Comment: join works too: names_and_ranks = [". ".join ([str(i+1), name]) for i, name in zip(city_indices, city_names)]

Answer (score 0):

Use *zip* and *list comprehension*:

```
combined = ['{0}. {1}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in zip(city_indices, city_names)]
```

Output:

```
>>> combined = ['{0}. {1}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in zip(city_indices, city_names)]
>>> print(combined)
['0. Buenos Aires', '1. Toronto', '2. Pyeongchang', '3. Marakesh', '4. Albuquerque', '5. Los Cabos', '6. Greenville', '7. Archipelago Sea', '8. Walla Walla Valley', '9. Salina Island', '10. Solta', '11. Iguazu Falls']
>>>
```